# Односоставное или двусоставное предложение (см.)?

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении *"Задача обсуждалась на педсовете"* какой член предложения "задача"? Я думаю, что это неопределенно-личное предложение, где сказуемое "обсуждалась", а "задача" — дополнение. Так ли это (мне говорят, что "задача" подлежащее)?

Answer (score 4):

> В предложении "Задача обсуждалась на педсовете" - какой член
>   предложения "задача". Я думаю, что это неопределенно-личное
>   предложение, где сказуемое "обсуждалась", а "задача" - дополнение.

Попробуйте определить падеж слова "задача"... Именительный? Тогда дополнением быть не может. ПОДЛЕЖАЩЕЕ.

**Предложение двусоставное.**

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Существительное [задача](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0) склоняется таким образом:
зада́ча, зада́чи, зада́че, зада́чу (В. п.), зада́чей (зада́чею), зада́че.

Выяснили, что слово "задача" стоит в именительном падеже, значит, оно является подлежащим: **обсуждалась** (что?) **задача.** Предложение является двусоставным.

Неопределенно-личным оно было бы в таком виде: **Задачу обсуждали на педсовете.**
В нем нет подлежащего, а используется только сказуемое (глагол множественного числа прошедшего времени) с второстепенными членами.

[Неопределённо-личные предложения](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/primeryi-neopredelyonno-lichnyih-predlozheniy.html)

Comment: Спасибо!! (Не  умею я курсивом писать - отправьте, пожалуйста, мою благодарность Римме Михайловой).